# Get Purchased Items for a Customer

Tags: orders, customer-account, items

How to get all items purchased by a customer.

Thank you for all the responses. But my issue is that I am trying to show all products in the My Downloadable Products Page. But the following code,

```
$_items = $this->getItems();
```

in the `default/template/downloadable/products/list.phtml`

the `$_items` are all downloadable products only. How can I get all products there?

Comment: using code? or else..

Comment: Using Code Please..

Comment: I want to get all the purchased items for the logged in customer.. Please help

Answer (score 8):

**First You need to call Sales Order item collection:**

```
$collection = Mage::getResourceModel('sales/order_item_collection')
            ->addAttributeToSelect('*');
```

**Then put relation with sales_flat_order for getting customer email,customer id**

```
$collection->getSelect()->join( array('orders'=> sales_flat_order),
 'orders.order_id=main_table.order_id',array('orders.customer_email','orders.customer_id'));
```

**then get current customer id from session and filter by customer id using below code**

```
if (Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn()) {

     $customer = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer();
     $customer->getId();
    $collection->->addFieldToFilter('customer_id',$customer->getId())
  }
```

**Then get Product Id from collection:**

```
foreach($collection as $EachItem){

        $EachItem->getProductId();
    }
```

Full code:

```
if (Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn()) {

    $collection = Mage::getResourceModel('sales/order_item_collection')
    ->addAttributeToSelect('*');
    $collection->getSelect()->join( array('orders'=> sales_flat_order),
    'orders.order_id=main_table.order_id',array('orders.customer_email','orders.customer_id'));

    $customer = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer();

    $collection->addFieldToFilter('customer_id',$customer->getId());

    foreach($collection as $EachItem){

        $EachItem->getProductId();
    }
  }
```

**Alternative solution:**

```
if (Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn()) {

    $orders= Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection()->addAttributeToFilter('customer_id',Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer()->getId());
    foreach($orders as $eachOrder){
        $order = Mage::getModel("sales/order")->load($eachOrder->getId()); 

        $items = $order->getAllVisibleItems();
           foreach($items as $item):
              echo $item->getProductId();
           endforeach;
       }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. But my issue is that I am trying to show all products in the My Downloadable Products Page. But the following code,

$_items = $this->getItems();

in the default/template/downloadable/products/list.phtml

the $_items are all downloadable products only. How can I get all products there?

Comment: is there a way to get frequently ordered item for each customer?

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
//Todo : get current customer id $customerId
$items = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection()
       ->join(array('item' => 'sales/order_item'), 'main_table.entity_id = item.order_id')
       ->addFieldToFilter('customer_id', $customerId);

foreach($items as $item){
    if ($item->isDeleted() && $item->getParentItemId()) { continue; }
    echo $item->getName()
}
```

See [How to get Magento customer ID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14903646/how-to-get-magento-customer-id)

Comment: Hi Could you please tell what this line of code does?
if ($item->isDeleted() && $item->getParentItemId()) { continue; }

Comment: Take a look at getAllVisibleItems() see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18741873/getallvisibleitems-getallitems-returns-items-twice

Answer (score 1):

**To get all the products of a LoggedIn Customer with order status 'Complete'**

```
 orders = Mage::getResourceModel('sales/order_collection')
->addFieldToSelect('*')
->addFieldToFilter('customer_id', Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer()->getId())
->addFieldToFilter('state', array('in' =>Mage::getSingleton('sales/order_config')->getVisibleOnFrontStates()))
->addFieldToFilter('status', 'complete')
->setOrder('created_at', 'desc');

$this->setOrders($orders);
foreach ($orders as $order)
{
$order_id=$order->getRealOrderId();
$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($order_id, 'increment_id');
$order->getAllVisibleItems();
$orderItems = $order->getItemsCollection()
->addAttributeToSelect('*')
->addAttributeToFilter('product_type', array('eq'=>'simple'))
->load();
foreach($orderItems as $Item)
{
$Item = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->setStoreId($Item->getStoreId())->load($Item->getProductId());
if ($Item->getId())
{
    echo $Item->getName();
    echo $Item->getPrice();
    echo $Item->getProductUrl();
    echo $Item->getImageUrl();
    }
}
}
?>
```

Comment: how can I get in magento 2 I have the only customerId.