# Get all purchased skus of customers in Magento 2

Tags: magento2.3

I have created a Magento 2 module that downloads a csv file from a controller but I need to get all the purchased skus (no duplicates) of each customer in the csv.

The csv file is going to have the following details

```
customer_email  | sku_bought
123@example.com | sku_a, sku_b
234@example.com | sku_b, sku_c
```

Comment: Jaimin Sutariya's answer for Magento 1 is similar to what I need: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/184409/get-all-orders-purchased-products-for-each-customer

Comment: You just need to transfer the code from M1 to M2, what is the current issue you are having?

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like that:

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$customerId = '123';
$orderCollection = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Collection');
$orderCollection->addAttributeToFilter('customer_id',$customerId)
            ->addAttributeToFilter('status','complete')
            ->load();
echo "<pre>";print_r($orderCollection->getData()); exit;
```

> Note: It's just only a hint. You can get all purchased products from
> **$orderCollection**. 
>  Please avoid Objectmanager and use dependency Injection for code.